# Kernel Stuck in GeosSpatial Analysis Kaggle micro-course

Tags: google-analytics, jupyter-notebook, kernel, geospatial, kaggle

While doing the Kaggle GeoSpatial analysis micro-course on kaggle, my kernel/notebook is getting stuck at two cells in the Proximity Analysis exercise notebook and taking up a lot of CPU resources. Since the problem could be my code, I ran the solution the instructors @jessicali9530 and @alexisbcook gave. Now, I don't know where the problem lies, It's either:

1. A problem with the solution.
2. A problem with the checking system.
3. A problem in how the kernels/notebooks are executed, on kaggle servers or on my system.[My system - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1280 V2 @ 3.60GHz 3.60 GHz]

I've attached screenshots of the problem below. I'm new Kaggle,so please tell me if I've done something wrong in running the notebook (there were no problems on previous micro-courses).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the link to my kernel --> [Kernel link](https://www.kaggle.com/siddalore/exercise-proximity-analysis/) (you'd have to download the code to run it, as kaggle cannot make an html if there is error in the code).

What I've tried so far but with similar results:

1. I tried running the notebook on differnt PCs with the same processor config.
2. I tried deleting the notebook and running it again.
3. I removed all of my code and tried the Instructors solutions.
4. I tried closing down all other windows and programs running in the background (I don't know if it helps)

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the very same problem with the very same outcome. From the traceback it seems clear that the error reported is not related to the student code itself but to the check() method utilized for code verification. I submitted a formal request for help from Kaggle through the 'More' option on the main menu: "More > Support/Contact > I found an issue with the website". I commit to share with you any reply I may get in the future. Please do the same if you succeed on your attempts. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Paulo, I had asked the same question on the Kaggle forums to which the Kaggle Team responded with a workaround solution. Here's the link for the Discussion Thread to follow through --> [Kernel Stuck in GeosSpatial Analysis course](https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/129634)

Comment: Hi @Siddharth, thanks for your help! The code suggested worked for me. Apparently the change indicated by instructor Alexis Cook has not yet been implemented in the exercise notebook. Anyway, I could finally complete the course. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been solved(atleast a workaround) by the Kaggle Team in the discussion thread here --> [Kernel Stuck in GeosSpatial Analysis course](https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/129634). The kernel will some time to run which is to be expected and normal.